# Como compilar um .C/C++ em meu site

Tags: php, c, c++, compiladores

Existe algum modo de compilar um arquivo .C/C++ dentro de um site? digamos que será gerado um "arquivo.c" e este arquivo será compilado... talvez tenha como fazer isso em PHP ou com algum complemento.

Comment: Oi Jefter, voce quer dizer fazer algo parecido com o que o [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) faz? Na teoria você pode chamar o gcc (ou algum outro compilador) com [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), por exemplo `exec("g++ arquivo.c", $saida);`, mas tome bastante cuidado com as implicações para a segurança (ataques ao compilador) e *performance* (processos  rodando por muito tempo ou até mesmo travando...).

Comment: na verdade o que eu pretendia era copilar o arquivo e cuspi-lo para o cliente

Comment: O que voce gostaria de cuspir para o cliente exatamente? A saída da compilação (erros, etc?)? Ou você pretende compilar, executar e devolver o que o aplicativo jogou na *standard output*? Ou ainda gostaria de compilar e devolver o binário para o cliente?

Comment: Sim, existe inúmeras formas. Por exemplo, supondo que o compilador (e as bibliotecas dais quais ele depende) estão instaladas no servidor rodando o PHP, você pode simplesmente usar a função [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php). Talvez você possa também implementar uma integração com um serviço como o [Sphere Engine](http://sphere-engine.com/) do [Ideone](http://ideone.com/). Mas a escolha vai depender do que você intenciona devolver ao cliente, como o colega @AnthonyAccioly bem perguntou. Edite a questão para deixá-la mais clara/específica, ok?

Comment: Um bom artigo que consegui achar com alguns minutos de pesquisa é [este](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-online-compiler-for-C-C++-and-Java-using-node-js-as-server-language) Basicamente pelo que entendi você quer montar um compilador online.